# How to ignore the false positive issues found in OWASP Zap scan that runs in CI/CD Pipeline?

Tags: gitlab, pipeline, owasp, zap

We have integrated OWASP ZAP in Gitlab CI/CD. After scanning a web application, we then relayed the issues to the developers. After the developers have assessed the issues, they found out that some of the issues found are false positives. So the problem is, how do we configure ZAP to mark those issues as False Positives on the next run in the pipeline?
We are using the stable version of OWASP ZAP Docker image.
All of your inputs are much welcome, thank you!

Comment: How are you running ZAP? Using a packaged scan or ??
We have a pretty thorough FAQ here: https://www.zaproxy.org/faq/how-do-i-handle-a-false-positive/

Comment: Hi @SimonBennetts , we used the Docker image of ZAP - owasp/zap2docker-stable and used the packaged scan which is the full scan. We'd integrated it in CI/CD, so the goal here is to mark the issues as false positives when running the scan again in the pipeline.

Comment: Have you read the FAQ I linked above? :)